# Firebase Realtime Database: Listen to changes with specific values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following DB structure:

```
 Users
     Test
          ID:1
          category:2
     Test1
         ID:2
         category:3
     Test3: 
         ID:3 
         category:2
```

Now I want to listen to any changes on Users child that only have category value 2.

How I can do that in Firebase.

Comment: why not you query all the users' data and add a listener for every user who has category = 2?

Answer (score 2):

as David Ibrahim says, you can use query to listen changes for the category with that value 2. You can something like this.

```
Query queryCategory = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").orderByChild("category").equalTo(2);
        queryCategory.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```